# Entering a value into an Array of Points?

Tags: java

So I want to input the two coordinates of the point into the array. Sorry if this is way off, I'm very confused.

```
//create array of 100 coordinate points
//Excerpt from Main

Point[] A = new Point[100];


Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter index: ");

int i = in.nextInt(); //validate

System.out.print("Enter integers x, y to replace: ");

A[i].input(in);
```

...

```
public class Point {

  int x, y;

  Point(int x, int y) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
  }

  void input(Scanner sc){
    x = in.nextInt();
    y = in.nextInt();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A[i].input(in);` is not valid syntax. You must add a new `Point` object into your array. In order to do this, you must have enough information from the user to create a `Point` object.

You want to do something closer to this:

```
//create array of 100 coordinate points

Point[] A = new Point[100];


Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter index: ");

int i = in.nextInt(); //validate

System.out.print("Enter integers x, y to replace: ");

int x = in.nextInt();
int y = in.nextInt();

a[i] = new Point(x, y);
```

In your constructor for `Point`, you are throwing an error. Delete the line where you are throwing the error, and instead use it to assign the value.

```
...
Point(int x, int y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I'm still lost. I'm getting the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException", I updated the post to add my Point.java.